# How to get the first occurence of the element in the list from a given string?

Tags: python

```
string = 'get selected items from the list'

lst_keywords = ['list', 'selected', 'python', 'subset']

res = [ele for ele in lst_keywords if(ele in string)] 

then res = ['list', 'selected']
```

But I only want the first occurrence of element present in the string, like in the string since selected comes first I just want res to output `selected` only excluding the `list` element from res.

Any ideas of how I can achieve that?

Comment: `next(ele for ele in lst_keywords if ele in string)`

Comment: @Christ_Rands @OP How does it answer the question? It gives the first item from `lst_keywords` that is in the string, i.e. "list"; it does *not* output the element (word) that is *first* in the string ("selected"). The latter appears what is being asked, given the penultimate paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
string = 'get selected items from the list'
lst_keywords = ['list', 'selected', 'python', 'subset']
v_ = [str1 for str1 in string.split() if str1 in lst_keywords][0]
print(v_)
```

**Result**

```
selected
```

Comment: Yup, the preferred way is what you have mentioned.

Comment: Hey @AnswerSeeker, thanks for that answer , just want to know if I add one more element in lst_keywords  like 'get selected' so now I have 5 items in the list and from the raw string since 'get selected' comes first so it should output that element from the list.

Comment: For two connected words, algorithm will have to apply bigrams and perform a search.